# Create Login command error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

What is wrong here in following screen shot? [image]

I am trying solutions posted [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sqlman/archive/2011/06/14/tips-amp-tricks-you-have-lost-access-to-sql-server-now-what.aspx) and [here](http://v-consult.be/2011/05/26/recover-sa-password-microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2/) to add a login

Comment: I would guess you are connected to SQL 2000 instance. Please verify the output of SELECT @@VERSION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you 100% sure that this is SQL Server 2008?  This behavior suggests SQL Server 2000.

The SQL Server 2000 syntax was

```
EXEC sp_addlogin 'recovery', 'ThePassword';
GO
```

Try that.  If that works, when you get into the server check the compatibility level of all your databases in addition to running `select @@VERSION`.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot looks strange.
First of all, SQLCMD  don't work with SQL Server 2000.
Among this, parameter `-s` means colseparator and not a server name. For servername usage the parameter `-S` need to be specified.

I tried the script like yours on SQL Server 2005 and 2008 and it works fine. [image]

Additional information according to SQLCMD usage can be found here:

- [SQL Server 2005](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)
- [SQL Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
- [SQL Server 2008 R2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [SQL Server 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)